# Paused on exception TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, django-templates

Well Here I am creating commenting system. It works fine if there is at least one comment already but if there is no comment and try to create one than it shows me an error **Paused on exception
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null** . I don't know how can i fix it.

html

```
  <div id="post_id" post-id="{{post.pk}}" post-slug="{{post.slug}}">    
        {% if node.level < 3 %} 
        <button class='btn btn-success' onclick="myFunction({{node.id}})">Reply</button>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
```

jquery,ajax funtion

```
$(document).on('click', '#newcomment, #newcommentinner', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var button = $(this).attr("value");
    var post_id = document.getElementById('post_id').getAttribute('post-id'); #Here is an error appearing.
    var post_slug = document.getElementById('post_id').getAttribute('post-slug');
    console.log(post_id,'postid')
    var placement = "commentform"
    if (button == "newcommentform") {
      var placement = "newcommentform"
    }
 
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{% url "posts:addcomment" %}',
      data: $("#" + button).serialize() + "&post_id="+post_id + "&post_slug="+post_slug,
      cache: false,
      error: console.log('post_id' + post_id),
      success: function (json) {
        console.log(json)

        $('<div id="" class="my-2 p-2" style="border: 1px solid grey"> \
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">By ' + json['user'] + '<div></div>Posted: Just now!</div> \
          <div>' + json['result2'] + '</div> \
          <hr> \
          </div>').insertBefore('#' + placement);

        $('.commentform').trigger("reset");
        formExit()
      },
      error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
      }
    });
  })
```

if more code is require than tell me in comment session. i will update my question with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why would you mess jQuery syntax with plain JS? :)

```
var post_id = $('#post_id').attr('post-id')
```

should do it.